# CSS flex layout with an image height relative to visible page and with maximum relative width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the below layout.

[image]

I have a region that, ideally, fills most of browser's height; I want it all within view, with a potential minimum height. On the left is an image that stretches to fill the area, with the aspect retained, but will not go beyond a maximum width.  On the right is a div that takes up the remaining space.

I can't figure out the HTML and CSS flex-box styles that would achieve it.

Comment: Could you include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Rojo No, I can't. That's the point of the question. I don't know how to achieve this layout.

Comment: suppose you have a long narrow window.  60% max width could be considerably less than 80% of the height.  What to do in that case?

Comment: @DCR I'd like it to be constrained to the 60% width in that case and take a height relative to the aspect ratio.

Comment: i'm not sure this can be done with flexbox but it seems relatively straight forward with javascript. Get the window dimensions, get the image dimensions, do some math, set widths and heights of elements